# loadtxt error in python

Tags: python, pycharm

I am having trouble to load a file in the python. I am running `pycharm` after activating `virualenv`.

I am trying to load the `softdata.txt` and it is in the same folder of `softmax classification.py`

The following error occurs: `No such file or directory: 'softdata.txt'`

[image]

I don't get it why it happens. Please help me out.

Comment: Could you add a monitor view of `softdata.txt`? I don't see the extension. Also there are two `softdata`'s. Which one are you trying to load?

Comment: Can you please paste the code. I can't see nothing on that screenshot

Comment: Oh. the one in the below? I copied and pasted the "softdata.txt" file in several directory to find the correct directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python files cannot have spaces in the file name. This is because Python files (`.py`) are actually modules that are importable, and you cannot have modules with a space in the name.

The error is actually at the bottom of the screen, where it says:

`Cannot start process, the working directory '/root/PycharmProjects/tensorflow study/softmax' does not exist`

Note it stopped at *softmax* even though the file is called *softmax classification.py*.

The simple solution is to rename the file and remove the space; so the file `softmax classification.py` is `softmaxclassification.py`.

You may also want to rename `current directory.py` to `currentdirectory.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I renamed it and tried again. But the same error.

Comment: It is solved. it was because of the space between file names. Thanks again and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

are you 100% sure that softdata is a .txt file? i dont see the extension
[image]

I also noticed the following
[image]

It doesnt seem to be reading into the multifeature filepath

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I have checked the attribution of the file

Comment: can you remove the .txt extension from your script, and just use np.loadtxt("softdata", etc....)

Comment: otherwise, try using genfromtxt  instead of loadtxt, i think that for loadtxt you must enter an address (file path) and not just the filename. so if you want to try loadtxt, try entering the documents full path.

Comment: I tried and it shows hell of errors. the errors are as below

Comment: it is too long to add here. :)

Comment: can you show me how to use "genfromtxt" if you don't bother? I am completely new to the computer programming. a smaple code may be enough.

Comment: just need to do the following: np.genfromtxt('softdata.txt', other, variables)

Comment: Thanks. but the same error shows up. it seems like "softdata.txt" doesn't exit in the directory.

Comment: last comment I have. transfer your files from the multifeature folder up one level. i think this is the problem. you might have to rename 1 of the softdata files, since you will end up with 2.